# How can I make a whole listings line into a hyperlink?

Tags: hyperref, listings

Let's say I have a document with a listings. And I want to convert that listing into a hyperlink (e.g. to the source code).

The first instinctive attempt will be something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,}
\begin{document}
  \href{file}{
    \begin{lstlisting}[columns=fullflexible, backgroundcolor=\color{black!20}]
      code code
    \end{lstlisting}
  }
\end{document}
```

This fails because of know limitation (see [Strange interaction between hyperref, listings and animate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184922/strange-interaction-between-hyperref-listings-and-animate))

The second attempt will be to create a escape inside the code:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[columns=fullflexible, backgroundcolor=\color{black!20}, escapeinside={\%*}{*)}]
   %*\href{file}{Link}*)code code
\end{lstlisting}
```

(Note, above the line starting with `%` is not a comment because but a escape combination in a verbatim/lstlistings)

This works but still doesn't cover the whole environment (or at least something that covers most of the line).

I need something like this (fake code to make the typeset code into a link)

```
\begin{lstlisting}[columns=fullflexible, backgroundcolor=\color{black!20}, escapeinside={\%*}{*)}]
   "\href"{file}{code code}
\end{lstlisting}
```

**How can I convert most of the listings line into a hyperlink?** I am mostly interested in one-line (or very short) listings.

Comment: What do you mean by "most of the listing"? The entire frame? Just the text? A selection of lines?

Comment: @Jubobs, ideally the whole frame (or the whole line). The code text part only (in case it is shorter than the whole line)  is also acceptable. It looks like your (great) answer does the second.

Comment: Ok. See my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following approach (borrowed from [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213013/21891)) allows you to turn the *text* of the listing (but not the whole *frame/box*) into a hyperlink. First, save the listing in an `lrbox`; then, use the latter in the second argument of `\href`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newsavebox\lstA

\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,}

\begin{document}
\begin{lrbox}{\lstA}
\begin{lstlisting}[
    columns=fullflexible,
    backgroundcolor=\color{black!20},
    gobble=4,
]
    code code
\end{lstlisting}
\end{lrbox}
\href{http://www.google.com}{\usebox{\lstA}}
\end{document}
```

**Edit**: with the same approach but using `tcolorbox` instead of `listings`, you can turn the whole *box* into a hyperlink. You may have to tweak the box's appearance to your liking, but if you're going to typeset your listings inside fancy boxes, you're better off using `tcolorbox` anyway.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcblisting{mylisting}{%
  spartan,
  boxrule = 0pt,
  colback = black!20,
  listing only,
  listing options = {%
    basicstyle = \ttfamily,
    columns    = fullflexible,
    gobble     = 4,
  }
}
\newsavebox\lstA

\begin{document}
\begin{lrbox}{\lstA}
\begin{mylisting}
code code
code code
\end{mylisting}
\end{lrbox}
\href{http://www.google.com}{\usebox{\lstA}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `tcolorbox` solution doesn't compile. I see this `Library (tcolorbox): 'tcblistings.code.tex' version '2.60'
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcblistingscore.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcblistingscore.code.tex' version '2.60'
)))) (./hyperref.aux)` and after a few lines the interactive LaTeX prompt. The first solution works as expected.

Comment: @alfC The second solution works fine for me. Is your tex distribution up to date?

Comment: Maybe not. `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.6-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2014/dev)` (from Fedora 20). `tcbox` is 2.60. I'll try again after upgrading the system in a few weeks.