# Why are there blank horizontal gaps in my listing/lstlisting background?

Tags: listings, line-spacing

There are horizontal gaps in my `listings` code block when I change the background color. This minimal working example code and screenshot demonstrate the issue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\linespread{0.67}\ttfamily,
    backgroundcolor=\color{gray}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
n := 42;
for i in [1,2,3,4,5] do
    n := n+i;
od;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of issue]

I know a linespread of ⅔ is ridiculous, I'm just accentuating the problem with this example. The real issue is that *these gaps appear, albeit very faintly, even for a linespread of 1!*

[image: linespread of 1 faint lines screenshot]

What's going on here and how can I fix this?

Comment: yes it can happen if the font is a bit too large. Use tcolorbox if you want listings with background, its code for this is better.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer this seems like such a *drive a nail with a sledgehammer* solution

Comment: well listings colors lines and this can always give this gaps. If you want to avoid it, you need another painting system, and listings doesn't have it.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap `lstlistings` in a `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\tcolorboxenvironment{lstlisting}{
  spartan,
  frame empty,
  boxsep=0mm,
  left=1mm,right=1mm,top=-1mm,bottom=-1mm,
  colback=gray!45,
}


\lstset{
    basicstyle=\linespread{0.67}\ttfamily,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
n := 42;
for i in [1,2,3,4,5] do
    n := n+i;
od;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This isn't my favorite solution since it involves including another package and wrapping each `lstlisting` environment in another environment, but [Ulrike Fischer's suggestion in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598393/why-are-there-blank-horizontal-gaps-in-my-listing-lstlisting-background#comment1500191_598393) of using `tcolorbox` works, and it add pleasing margins to the code block.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\linespread{0.67}\ttfamily,
    %backgroundcolor=\color{gray},
}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{tcolorbox-code}{%
    colback=gray, %
    colframe=gray, %
    sharp corners %
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox-code}
\begin{lstlisting}
n := 42;
for i in [1,2,3,4,5] do
    n := n+i;
od;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{tcolorbox-code}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of what the code outputs]

Comment: well tcolorbox has dedicated environments for code that you can use.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I saw that briefly, but it looked like it was specific to TeX code, and then it complained about a comment line starting with a `#` character, then it wasn't syntax-highlighting my code right, and then it turned into more of a hassle to learn to use the sledgehammer properly to drive the nail than to just clumsily drop the sledgehammer around the nail until the job was done

Comment: I echo the use of `tcolorbox` for code listings. Here's how I did it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/583367/218142.

Answer (score 0):

I found this workaround. We can add frames to the lines, and set the frame's border to 0 width. It removed the vertical gaps between lines for me.

```tex
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  columns=flexible,
  breaklines=true,
  backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
  frame=ltb,
  framerule=0pt,
}
```