interline space between backgroundcolor in lstlisting
I have an issue with backgroundcolor in a lstlisting. There is a gap in between some line.

My code :
\documentclass{article}
    % Packages images
% \usepackage{graphicx}
% \usepackage{caption}
% \usepackage{subcaption}
% \graphicspath{ {./fig/} }
% \usepackage{enumitem}

    % Packages mise en page
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{
    a4paper,
    hmargin = 2cm,
    top = 2cm
}

    % Package code
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage[svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{inconsolata}


\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0.23}
\definecolor{codeblue}{rgb}{0.13,0.18,0.9}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.85,0.85,0.82}

\lstdefinestyle{VBA}{
    language={[Visual]Basic},
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},  
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{codeblue},
    basicstyle=\linespread{0.8}\ttfamily,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    xleftmargin=-1.5cm, xrightmargin=-1cm,
    morestring=[s]""
}
\lstset{style=VBA}

\title{Documention Technique}
\author{Lidwyn Le Bars}
\date{23 Septembre 2024}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{enumerate}
\item Sub ExportToXml()

Sub ExportToXml est une procédure qui a pour but deux chose :
\begin{itemize}
    \item Vérifier les noms d'entrées
    \item Appeler la fonction de compilation pour chaque compilation demandée
\end{itemize}

Dans un premier temps on pose les réferrences vers les classeurs (workbook) et les feuilles (worksheet) ainsi que la référence au chemin (path) de l'emplacementd du classeur

\begin{lstlisting}
Sub ExportToXml()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    Dim RootPath As String: RootPath = wb.path & "\"
\end{lstlisting}

Ici on pose wb comme le classeur actuel (thisworkbook) et ws comme la première feuille (et unique feuille) du classeur actuel. RootPath prend comme valeurs le chemin du classeur et on ajoute un "\textbackslash" au bout de la chaine de charactère.

Ensuite on passe au test de noms des fichiers d'entrées et du fichier de sortie.

\begin{lstlisting}
        ' Test des entrees
    Dim row As Integer: row = 6
    Dim column As Integer: column = 3
    Dim ErrorType As Integer    '1: probleme de nom vide; 2: probleme de type de format xml vs xlsx/xlsm; 3: fichier inexistant
    For i = 1 To ws.Cells(1, 3).Value
        For j = 0 To 4  ' 5 ligne a tester par simulation
            tmp = Split(ws.Cells(row + j, column).Value, ".")   ' decoupe de a ligne avec les "." pour recuperer l'extension
            If UBound(tmp) > 0 Then                                                                         ' test le nom n'est pas vide
                If tmp(UBound(tmp)) = "xlsx" And ws.Cells(row + j, column + 1).Value = "excel" Then         ' test que l'extension est bonne pour un xlsx
                    'nothing
                ElseIf tmp(UBound(tmp)) = "xlsm" And ws.Cells(row + j, column + 1).Value = "excel" Then     ' test que l'extension est bonne pour un xlsm
                    'nothing
                ElseIf tmp(UBound(tmp)) = "xml" And ws.Cells(row + j, column + 1).Value = "xml" Then        ' test que l'extension est bonne pour un xml
                    'nothing
                Else
                    ErrorType = 2
                    GoTo ErrorCatch ' erreur de type de format entre le format renseigne et le fichier renseigne
                End If
                If (Dir(RootPath & ws.Cells(row + j, column).Value) = "") And j <> 4 Then                   ' test que le fichier existe
                    ErrorType = 3
                    GoTo ErrorCatch
                End If
            Else
                ErrorType = 1 ' erreur dans le nom du fichier, case vide ou sans extension
                GoTo ErrorCatch
            End If
        Next j
        row = row + 7   ' on passe au information de la simulation en dessous
        If i = 4 Then   ' si on est la quatrieme simulation alors il faut aller a la deuxieme colonne d'information
            row = 6
            column = 7
        End If
    Next i
\end{lstlisting}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}


Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/661987/4427 help?

it does help but I added xleftmargin=-1.5cm, xrightmargin=-1cm so the text go out of the box

I manage to play with oversize, left and xleftmargin to get what I wanted

You should reduce the height of the monospaced font, anyway.

I used tcolorbox to created the background color:
\documentclass{article}

    % Packages mise en page
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{
    a4paper,
    hmargin = 2cm,
    top = 2cm
}

    % Package code
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage[svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}


\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0.23}
\definecolor{codeblue}{rgb}{0.13,0.18,0.9}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.85,0.85,0.82}

\lstdefinestyle{VBA}{
    language={[Visual]Basic},
    % backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},  
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{codeblue},
    basicstyle=\linespread{0.85}\ttfamily,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    xleftmargin=-1cm,
    morestring=[s]""
}

\tcolorboxenvironment{lstlisting}{
    spartan,
    oversize = 2cm,
    frame empty,
    boxsep=0mm,
    left=1cm,right=1mm,top=-1mm,bottom=-1mm,
    colback=gray!45
}

\lstset{style=VBA}

\title{Documention Technique}
\author{Lidwyn Le Bars}
\date{23 Septembre 2024}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{enumerate}
\item Sub ExportToXml()

Sub ExportToXml est une procédure qui a pour but deux chose :
\begin{itemize}
    \item Vérifier les noms d'entrées
    \item Appeler la fonction de compilation pour chaque compilation demandée
\end{itemize}

Dans un premier temps on pose les réferrences vers les classeurs (workbook) et les feuilles (worksheet) ainsi que la référence au chemin (path) de l'emplacementd du classeur

\begin{lstlisting}
Sub ExportToXml()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    Dim RootPath As String: RootPath = wb.path & "\"
\end{lstlisting}

Ici on pose wb comme le classeur actuel (thisworkbook) et ws comme la première feuille (et unique feuille) du classeur actuel. RootPath prend comme valeurs le chemin du classeur et on ajoute un "\textbackslash" au bout de la chaine de charactère.

Ensuite on passe au test de noms des fichiers d'entrées et du fichier de sortie.

\begin{lstlisting}
        ' Test des entrees
    Dim row As Integer: row = 6
    Dim column As Integer: column = 3
    Dim ErrorType As Integer    '1: probleme de nom vide; 2: probleme de type de format xml vs xlsx/xlsm; 3: fichier inexistant
    For i = 1 To ws.Cells(1, 3).Value
        For j = 0 To 4  ' 5 ligne a tester par simulation
            tmp = Split(ws.Cells(row + j, column).Value, ".")   ' decoupe de a ligne avec les "." pour recuperer l'extension
            If UBound(tmp) > 0 Then                                                                         ' test le nom n'est pas vide
                If tmp(UBound(tmp)) = "xlsx" And ws.Cells(row + j, column + 1).Value = "excel" Then         ' test que l'extension est bonne pour un xlsx
                    'nothing
                ElseIf tmp(UBound(tmp)) = "xlsm" And ws.Cells(row + j, column + 1).Value = "excel" Then     ' test que l'extension est bonne pour un xlsm
                    'nothing
                ElseIf tmp(UBound(tmp)) = "xml" And ws.Cells(row + j, column + 1).Value = "xml" Then        ' test que l'extension est bonne pour un xml
                    'nothing
                Else
                    ErrorType = 2
                    GoTo ErrorCatch ' erreur de type de format entre le format renseigne et le fichier renseigne
                End If
                If (Dir(RootPath & ws.Cells(row + j, column).Value) = "") And j <> 4 Then                   ' test que le fichier existe
                    ErrorType = 3
                    GoTo ErrorCatch
                End If
            Else
                ErrorType = 1 ' erreur dans le nom du fichier, case vide ou sans extension
                GoTo ErrorCatch
            End If
        Next j
        row = row + 7   ' on passe au information de la simulation en dessous
        If i = 4 Then   ' si on est la quatrieme simulation alors il faut aller a la deuxieme colonne d'information
            row = 6
            column = 7
        End If
    Next i
\end{lstlisting}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}```

